# Why is MySQL registering acuñar as a duplicate entry of acunar?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

**I have a verbs table in my MySQL database with the following columns:**

```
id smallint          UN AI PK
title varchar(25)
```

I have a script that tries to insert a new entry for the verb 'acuñar'. In the table, there already is an entry for a similarly spelled verb 'acunar'.

**Despite my MySQL DB storing UTF8 characters successfully, when I run the following Python script:**

```
import mysql.connector
import os
import io

db = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="12345678",
  database="polly_es",
  use_unicode=True,
  charset="utf8",
)

cursor = db.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO verb (title) VALUES ('acuñar')"

cursor.execute(sql)
```

**I get the following error:**

```
mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'acuñar' for key 'verb.title'
```

Yes, I am certain that there is no 'acuñar' entry already in the table.

And yes, my schema is encoded.

```
CREATE SCHEMA `polly_es` CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: The strings are compared using some collation. If two strings are duplicates where they must differ then specify correct collation. `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` is not correct in your case - alter it at least for this column.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because your collation is using `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` where the AI stands for

> AI refers to accent insensitivity. That is, there is no difference between e, è, é, ê and ë when sorting or comparing.

So you could try `utf8mb4_0900_as_ci`